# DayNight theme still follows System even when set to Day (light) mode in adapter

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme

I am using DayNight theme in my app. I am using the same adapter class in two places, one in a fragment and one in an activity. The layout I am using in the adapter has a view that will follow the DayNight theme. I have never set the mode to FOLLOW_SYSTEM in my code. But the view that is in the activity adapter always follows the system theme even when set to MODE_NIGHT_NO or MODE_NIGHT_YES. The adapter I use in the fragment works perfectly fine and follows the app theme and not the system theme. 
This is The view in my layout:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/overlay"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/col3_image_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/col3_image_height"
    android:background="@drawable/image_selected_bg"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

image_selected_bg:

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

<solid android:color="@color/selectedImage"/>
<corners android:radius="@dimen/rounded_corner_image_radius" />
</shape>
```

This is how I am using the view in my adapter

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: show us some code

Comment: I added the code. Have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that `@color/selectedImage` in `DayNight` theme would take reference to the default light color xml resource. Therefore you would need to create a new xml file for `@color/selectedImage` in a folder named `values-night`/`colors.xml`. I assume for the moment you have only `values`/`colors.xml`

Comment: I have two colors.xml files. One is default (LIGHT MODE) other one is with night tag for NIGHT MODE. The same adapter was working perfectly when I was using it in a fragment. The reason is the context I was passing to the adapter as a parameter. I was passing getApplicationContext() but I should've passed MyActivity.this. Now it works perfectly in activity too.Just changed the context paramter I was passing the adapter.